# Typescript - Remove last element from Parameters tuple, currying away last argument

Tags: typescript

I want to do currying with typescript and have:

```js
const findValueInDb = (value: number, dbSpec: string) => `found it, it's here: ${dbSpec}!`

const createFindValue = (dbSpec: string) =>
    (...params: Omit<Parameters<typeof findValueInDb>, "1">) => findValueInDb(...params, dbSpec)

const theResult = createFindValue("theDb")(10)
```

This does not work, and it would not be very flexible if arguments are added to the source function.  How can I define a currying contract? One that removes the last argument, but keeps the others?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In TypeScript 4 you can use an inferred tuple type to get all elements except the last (or first, etc.):

```
type Head<T extends any[]> = T extends [ ...infer Head, any ] ? Head : any[];
```

```
const findValueInDb = (value: number, dbSpec: string) => `found it, it's here: ${dbSpec}!`

const createFindValue = (dbSpec: string) =>
    (...params: Head<Parameters<typeof findValueInDb>>) => findValueInDb(...params, dbSpec)

const findValue = createFindValue("theDb")(10)
```

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhCGATAPAFShAHsCA7RAzlPLiANoC6AfFALxTpY75FlQB0nAlrgGYQAnWAkQAaYqSgUoAfmFIoALgnkKAbgBQGgMYB7XAWBRePRADV4AGwCuEAJK4AIgCM6UABQA3K7eW5rALbOguKIzgDKkNrKhgI8AOYAlHQ0AAa8utb4UFzA4rkA5EQAFoIQygAkAN5hkRDaAL4AhKlaegZG2gIIOABiphY20PTutVExwHG4SSkaUPMenOxg8ALwAQTKcEjIAAqr6xA4AgTIoJC6vMYDPvZOzlRUybQ0JviDtg4u7ksraxuhCJRRJtfSGa7vW5uLo9CD9SFDdwAImApRcSMS7gAjAAGEFAA)

Comment: This is excellent, I also built a Tail type, for removing the first argument.  This can be combined with a "spread" type: `(...args: [string, ...Tail<Params<typeof func>>]) => void`. This will explicitly retype the first argument. That, however, will loose the argument names, which the Tail/Head by them selves does not.

Comment: This is a fantastic solution - it even preserves the argument names, whereas other approaches may not. In my case, I needed to strip the last parameter in a call signature, and this elegantly solves the problem: `type RemoveLastParameter<T extends (...args: any) => any> = (...args: Head<Parameters<T>>) => ReturnType<T>;`

Comment: Why doesn't this work with `dbSpec?: string`? I get `params: any[]` inferred instead of `params: [value: number]`…

Comment: @mfulton26 Change `T extends` to `Required<T> extends` in `Head`. The issue is that with the optional parameter, that means the array could be (in this case) either 1 or 2 entries long, so the inference fails

Comment: Still have to put some thought into how that would work in a curried function though

Comment: Thank you @MingweiSamuel. My use case isn't in a curried function so this should work great for me for now.

Comment: @MingweiSamuel The paramter names are lost. how do I get them back?

Comment: @StavAlfi As long as you're on Typescript 4.0 or later, the parameter names should be preserved even through the currying. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhCGATAPAFShAHsCA7RAzlPLiANoC6AfFALxTpY75FlQB0nAlrgGYQAnWAkQAaYqSgUoAfmFIoALgnkKAbgCwAKG0BjAPa4CwKLx6IAavAA2AVwgBJXABEARnSgAKABYRr1-QB1fQFrRGVcWwBbV0FxRFcAZUhdZWMBHgBzAEo6GgADXn1bfCguYHFygHIiXwEIZQASAG8E5IhdAF8AQnztPUNjKF16+BwAMXMrO2h6TzaUtOAM3By87ShNr052MHgBeCiCZTgkZAAFfcOIHAECZFBIfV5TKZt7JzcqKlzaGjN8NMPi5XJ4dnsDkd4kkUtl+loAPQI4aDExREDjXDKHx+ALBULhKCRGKCX40dJZAZGNEY3AeEYICZvGaeABEwF8blZ2TUQA)