# how to reference all parameters except last in typescript

Tags: typescript

Similar to this quesiton: [how to reference all parameters except first in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024617/how-to-reference-all-parameters-except-first-in-typescript)

But here, I Want to get all parameters except the last one.

The accepted answer over there did not work in this use case.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript - Remove last element from Parameters tuple, currying away last argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63789897/typescript-remove-last-element-from-parameters-tuple-currying-away-last-argum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with an inferred rest type, but it gets slightly complicated by trailing optional arguments, which break the rest-type matching. To deal with this, the parameters can be wrapped in non-optional singleton tuples, which can be unwrapped in the resulting initial parameters.

```
type Wrap<T> = {[K in keyof T]-?: [T[K]]}
type Unwrap<T> = {[K in keyof T]: Extract<T[K], [any]>[0]}

type InitialParameters<F extends (...args: any) => any> =
  Wrap<Parameters<F>> extends [...infer InitPs, any] ? Unwrap<InitPs> : never

const f1 = (str: string, n?: number, b?: boolean) => {}

const f2 = (to: string, overrides?: number) => {}

type Test1 = InitialParameters<typeof f1>
// [str: string, n: number | undefined]

type Test2 = InitialParameters<typeof f2>
// [to: string]
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.6.2#code/C4TwDgpgBA6gTgQzAHgCoD4oF4oG8DaA0lAJYB2UA1hCAPYBmUqAugLQD8AXFPqkc8wC+AKFCQoAVTIB3RCgzY8RUhWp1GLbgFEAHsEQBjYGn4AaHgjIhm6fAAYhw0eGgBJMiWAkEAGwAKCIgAthDAEHAAzsgAYlAQehBkACYRUAAUAHRZgQDmEdyWIACU2JiFmFjCULByyAHBoeFR0eiY8WHJqfhZGeT04VDunn4R5oXMUOySMrVDwCOY3GQQAG7hTga0ZBHAUPQAjIppO3DcJ+Q55mRcUGQArkEARuHmjzePtLQ+EJYlWJi4ETCTbbXb0ABMR2AtDO+gu5loazgcBISQgERu9ye4T+AKBYmgqHRwEOODm3n8gQQITCkWQBIYe326GEAHpWdUoAA9dhOAlMYmQskeLy+erUxp0hmMCEs9mcnnCIA)

Comment: How can I prevent losing the paramter names?

Comment: @StavAlfi What do you mean exactly? In the type `Test`, the labels `str` & `n` are the parameter names. (playground link was broken, but now it works)

Comment: @StavAlfi I guess you meant to put that comment on another answer? Anyway, regarding your deleted comment, the version above works with trailing optional arguments.

Answer (score -1):

First,
`reverse()`

and

```
function aa(a1,...rest){
    console.log(a1,"",rest);
}
```